# How I can I add audio to my ffmpeg stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, ffserver

I want to add audio to my ffmpeg cli bellow

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vf format=yuv420p http://localhost:8080/feed.ffm
```

I tried `-acodec libmp3lame, -c:a libmp3lame` but it does not seam to work

Comment: Please avoid crossposting. Didn't see that you posted this to [su] too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an audio input. Assuming ALSA:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -video_size 1920x1080 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -sample_rate 48000 -channels 2 -i hw:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p http://localhost:8080/feed.ffm
```

See [FFmpeg ALSA input documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#alsa) and [FFmpeg Wiki: ALSA](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA).